# How to set Toolwindow orientation in ProvideToolWindowAttribute as variable in VSExtension

Tags: c#, vs-extensibility, vspackage

My requirement is this MyToolWindow should be Docked to Top/Bottom/Left/Right based on API returned location.

ProvideToolWindowAttribute takes constant orientation may be top/bottom/left/right, but my location is coming from API so based on that I can't provide const .

```
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow),
    Style = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsDockStyle.docked,
    Window = "GUID Here", Orientation = ToolWindowOrientation.Top)]
```

I'm pretty sure there would be some way to pass variable orientation, could anyone suggest so.
[image]